# What's the number in the last node of this directed graph?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, graph-theory, computer-science

[image]

Hint 1

> This graph was chosen from a larger collection of graphs.

Hint 2

> Among the graphs mentioned in Hint 1, this particular graph is specified by the collection $\{ 3284, 6235, 6685, 6619, 116 \}$.

Hint 3

> The `calculation-puzzle` tag is included only to indicate that you need to calculate the final number, but this puzzle is not calculation-intensive.

Background on puzzle (Spoiler Alert)

> I got the idea for this puzzle from a [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8TRcZklX_Q), and decided to turn this into a graph puzzle with [graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html). The collection $\{ 3284, 6235, 6685, 6619, 116 \}$ was chosen at random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final node contains the number

> 6174

because

> each node's "successor" is obtained by taking the difference between the largest and smallest numbers obtainable by rearranging its digits. That is: descending order minus ascending order. So e.g. 3284 is followed by 8432-2348. All numbers are treated as having four digits, so 116 means 0116 and is followed by 6110-0116.

Comment: Interesting.  Do all 4-digit numbers converge to that value (or to the trivial other value)?

Comment: Yes, it turns out that they do.

Comment: It holds for all 4-digits numbers where at least one digit is distinct. For example, 9999, 0000, 4444, etc, will not work.